# How can I connect nodemcu with laptop wifi

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu

Question is odd, but I want to know that how I connect nodmcu with a laptop wifi without using any router. Is it possible if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure and activate the access point mode on NodeMCU. It creates a WiFi network and you can connect to this network with your computer.

Comment: @HasnainRaza, did this help? if yes accept the answer to mark the question solved